# What is correct solution to fetch user authentication from Sring Security in Spring AOP aspect?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-aop

I have an aspect that audit entities' creation, deleting etc. In audit I must fetch the user, that triggered entity change.

```
package com.sdx.rootservice.auditing.aspect;

import com.sdx.rootservice.auditing.model.AuditType;
import com.sdx.rootservice.auditing.service.interfaces.AuditLogService;
import com.sdx.rootservice.dto.lead.AppealTypeDto;
import com.sdx.rootservice.security.model.JwtAuthentication;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Optional;

@Component
@Aspect
@Log4j2
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuditAspect {

    private final AuditLogService auditLogService;

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.sdx.rootservice.controller.company.AppealTypeController.create(..))",
            returning = "appealTypeDto")
    public void afterAppealTypeCreated(AppealTypeDto appealTypeDto) {
        var userId = fetchUserId();
        var targetId = appealTypeDto.getId();
        log.debug("Created new appeal type: " + appealTypeDto);
        auditLogService.logChanges(userId, "AppealType", targetId, AuditType.CREATE);
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.sdx.rootservice.controller.company.AppealTypeController.delete(..)) && args(id)")
    public void afterAppealTypeDeleted(Long id) {
        var userId = fetchUserId();
        log.debug("Deleted new appeal type: " + id);
        auditLogService.logChanges(userId, "AppealType", id, AuditType.DELETE);
    }

    private Long fetchUserId() {
        var authentication = (JwtAuthentication) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return Optional.ofNullable(authentication)
                .map(JwtAuthentication::getId)
                .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

I am afraid, that if there are multiple request to create endpoint, Security's context may change because different thread will be run. What is correct solution to fetch user authentication from Sring Security in Spring AOP aspect?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you do not change the default `SecurityContextHolderStrategy` to `GlobalSecurityContextHolderStrategy` by changing the system property `spring.security.strategy` to `MODE_GLOBAL` , and can make sure that the `AuditAspect` will be invoked by the URL that is protected by the spring security,  you do not need to worry about it as spring security will make sure that when it finish processing a HTTP request , it will always clear the `SecurityContext`.

In the codes, it is done by the `FilterChainProxy#doFilter()` 's finally block  at [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/6d318914d58b3780b67faf62e55f016f97bfa089/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/FilterChainProxy.java#L204).